# How to fetch the Actions linked to an Object in the Facebook Open Graph (knowing only the Object URL)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, restfb

I would like to know how to fetch the Actions linked to an Object in the Facebook Open Graph (knowing only the Object URL)?

Is it possible?

Also, Can I fetch a specific user action based on a specific object (connections?)?

FYI: I'm using RestFB but I'm ready to implement any other solution to achieve my goal.

Thank you,
Dimitri

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I don't think this is possible. I believe the intent is that you keep track of all of the actions that you see and store them against the objects yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Action and objects are not connected in an absolute way, every time you post an object using an action you create a link and only by this link you can fetch the pair (action/object).

In fact with my custom namespace I have only one object that I publish with three different actions, and by knowing the object url I know nothing about the actions.

But having the ID of the post generated by the action you can know the action used, as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#read

Hope this helps